# PostgreSQL group by with interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

Well, I have a seemingly simple set of data but it gives me a lot of trouble.

This is an example of what my data look like:

```
quantity  price1  price2 date
100       1       0      2018-01-01 10:00:00
200       1       0      2018-01-02 10:00:00
50        5       0      2018-01-02 11:00:00
100       1       1      2018-01-03 10:00:00
100       1       1      2018-01-03 11:00:00
300       1       0      2018-01-03 12:00:00
```

I need to sum up "quantity" column grouped by "price1" and "price2" and it would be very easy but I need to take into account time changes of "price1" and "price2". Data is sorted by "date".

What I need is the last row to be not grouped with the first two although it has the same values for "price1" and "price2". Also I need to get minimal and maximal date of each interval.

The end result should looks like this:

```
quantity price1 price2 dateStart            dateEnd
300      1      0      2018-01-01 10:00:00  2018-01-02 10:00:00 
50       5      0      2018-01-02 11:00:00  2018-01-02 11:00:00
200      1      1      2018-01-03 10:00:00  2018-01-03 11:00:00
300      1      0      2018-01-03 12:00:00  2018-01-03 12:00:00
```

Any suggestions for a SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a gap and island problem. Use the following code:

```
select sum(quantity), price1, price2, min(date) dateStart, max(date) dateend 
from
(
    select *,
           row_number() over (order by date) -
           row_number() over (partition by price1, price2 order by date) grp
    from data
) t
group by price1, price2, grp
order by dateStart
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c92f5e9bccc16973d0e3127a790acf86)

The solution is based on an identification of consecutive sequences of `price1` and `price2`, which is done by a creation of the `grp` column. Once you isolate the consecutive sequences then you do a simple group by using `grp` as well.

Comment: Strange, in few cases when dates and times of two rows are exactly the same it makes new intervals. Any help with that?

Comment: @GeorgiBonchev could you prepare an example in dbfiddle?

Comment: Never mind, I add second parameter (oid) in the "order by" and it worked

Comment: Well, unfortunatelly "over partition by" is not supported in older versions of PostgreSQL like 8.0. Is there a way to run this in PostgreSQL 8.0?

Comment: @GeorgiBonchev row_number can be simulated using a self-join: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Comment: I tried it but still cannot make it work properly. Should I open new question?

Comment: @GeorgiBonchev yes

Answer (score 0):

I changed a little bit the accepted answer to catch the cases when "date" column of two rows next to each other are exactly the same. I added second parameter so they will be ordered in correct order (my table has "oid" column)

```
select sum(quantity), price1, price2, min(date) dateStart, max(date) dateend 
from
(
    select *,
           row_number() over (order by date, oid) -
           row_number() over (partition by price1, price2 order by date, oid) grp
    from data
) t
group by price1, price2, grp
order by dateStart
```